# Microsoft Word Default allowincell property 'destroys' formatting. Where does it come from?

Tags: vba, ms-word

We have a Win32 application that stitches together documents in Word via OLE from various fragments held in a database.  There is a Word Template with a set of macros designed to ensure that the Word Document cannot be saved to disk but will be saved back to the database.  So far, so good.  Let us assume the system works.

We have *readonly* users too.  The design is that a different template is used so these users may view documents.  This 'browser' template has been brain-damaged so that no saving of the file may occur.

I have identified a very specific circumstance when this design fails - when a graphic falls inside a table, the readonly template dumps it outside the table, which results in a total reformat of the whole document - definitely NOT what is required.

By saving a sample document in xml format, once for each case, I have shown that 'allowincell=false' appears in the bad document for each affected graphic.  It seems reasonable to suppose this is the culprit.  *The attribute is not mentioned at all in the good version*.  (Odd because MSDN states 'false' is the default value, at least in .NET)

It would help if I understood better the mechanism by which this value is being set.  If I had to make a guess I would suppose that the attribute is set to True (i.e not mentioned) because the original user has requested so simply by placing the graphic inside a table.

Ultimately my question is - what is the MINIMAL intervention I can make to solve this specific problem ?  Any suggestions as to how this might be approached would be most gratefully received.

Comment: Well I wouldnt have asked it if it was easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely you may not have set `LayoutInCell = True` for the image (along with its `WrapFormat` to `wdWrapSquare`, `wdWrapThrough`, `wdWrapTight` or `wdWrapTopBottom`). The default is always False and that translates to the VML of 'allowincell=false" that you're seeing. Again, make sure that `WrapFormat` is **not** `wdWrapNone` or `wdWrapInline` - just use one of the other ones above).

If this doesn't work, please supply us with more information. For example what version of Word? What is the "save" code for the brain-dead version. What "Save to Web Page" options are you using? Put a full and brain-dead version of the same document (redact as needed) in something like DropBox for us to examine.

Comment: I need to make it clear that the documents are generated by users, not by me.  My task is support the software that displays and manages the documents.

Comment: I had discovered the LayoutInCell property through my own investigations, and by setting it via a macro, I managed to get the graphics in the affected documents to remain anchored.  Thanks for the information about wdWrapNone and wdWrapInline.  When I have had a chance to perform some testing on my fix i will let you know hw i got on.  I suppose since you are the only contributor the bounty has to be yours :)

Comment: In later versions of Word - 2007 and 2010 - LayoutInCell is automatically set to True when a picture is inserted in a table, so the issue would get mitigated if/when your installions are upgraded. For now, if you have control over global templates, you could potentially monitor in a VBA solution for when a picture is inserted and where and then set that property automatically.

Comment: Do you know what would be the effect of setting LayoutInCell="t" for a graphic that was not already in a cell ?

Comment: yeah, from the VML I figured it was 2003 or below. I don't know what the effect of `LayoutInCell = True` would be. In 2007/2010 `True` is the default value. Setting it to `True` in earlier versions probably wouldn't haven't any affect, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: But this is the odd thing - if the default value is "true", which I established in my original question, why does switching templates set it to false ?  Is there some global property of the template that controls this behviour ?

Comment: Could you describe the process a bit more of "switching templates"? I'm not really understanding that. Let me try - so you have a db which exports document chunks to a .dot to create a new document on an end-user's desktop. Pictures in tables have a `LayoutInCell = True`. That user then pushes "save" and everything works fine. Then in the same scenario, you have db push document chunks to a different .dot, pictures in tables have a `LayoutInCell = True`, and an end-user does a "save as..." and saves as HTML. This second situation is where the failure happens with `allowincell=false`?

Comment: No, that is not correct. One user creates the document and this is saved in the database.  At this point the document is fine.  Another user who is a 'readonly' user can access the document through our software, which switches the template (attachedTemplate property If I remember correctly).  At this point their version of the document is ruined because the graphics have picked up the allowincell="false" from somewhere.  It is this somewhere that I really need to establish.

Comment: Can you post the attachedtemplate for examination?

Comment: I cannot post them on here but I would be happy to EMail them to you personally if you wish.